# Can I use a Java code to send mail from Windows Server 2012 RS?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I initially tried to write a code to send mail from localhost, but I am not sure how to setup server. Went through help topics regarding that, didn't help much.

Is it possible to write a Java code to send mail from Windows Server 2012?

If not, please please help me setup localhost in my Windows Server 2012. I'm lost.

This is the code that I used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.204.10.116"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "443");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Notification");
        message.setText("Successful!", "UTF-8"); // as "text/plain"
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        Transport.send(message);        
    }
}
```

This is the error that I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.204.10.116, port: 443;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Not sure what I'm supposed to make of this error.

Comment: yes, you can send mails using Java, but it'll take a bit more work than this. Also: your home server and "localhost" are not really synonyms.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am aware that my home server and LocalHost are different. I have tried both separately, but to no avail. Can you please brief the additional steps? Also is it possible to send mails using Java without Internet connection?

Comment: What is the IP "10.204.10.116"? Is SMTP server running there?

Comment: It is the address I got when I entered 'nslookup' in command prompt.

Comment: nslookup for what? Your known server? If it is available in your DNS you did not have to do this? Again, how do you know that this is the address where your SMTP server is running?

Comment: Hi Alex, I went through it again and realized that I am using the wrong host name. I had used the Windows server IP address instead of the SMTP server one. It is working now :) Thank you!